# Why are my X server configurations not taken into account?

Tags: xorg, 14.04

I know questions like that have been asked many times but I can't find a way to solve my problem even after reading them and trying the answers.

I have two screens on my desktop. Whatever I set to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or to the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf` files, this is how my desktop looks like when I log in (which is wrong because the wallpaper should cover the whole background on the right side):

[image]

Then I start nvidia-settings and when I change from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

and apply it, my desktop looks like this:

[image]

which makes absolutely no sense at all to me, because I haven't touched the main screen's resolution.

I can't find a way to make X11 remember to put the small screen on the right of the big neither, nor keep the big screen as the main screen.
I have tried multiple configuration files including this:

```
Section "Screen"

    # Removed Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    # Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-2: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1280+0, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select@1280x1024+1920+0,DFP-2:nvidia-auto-select@1920x1080+0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This issue appeared when I switched to 13.10. I have just switched to 14.04 but it hasn't improved anything.

My GPU is an nvidia GTS 450.

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this please ?

Edit: Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-2 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080      59.9*+   60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

DVI-I-1 should be on the right, DVI-I-2 on the left. I have tried

`Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: 1280x1024+1920+56, DVI-I-2: 1920x1080+0+0"` in both `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf` but the result is still the same at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is actually much simpler. Try opening the "Appearance" settings (right click on the Dekstop => Change Background) and set the background to "Fill":

[image]

---

If that doesn't work, try editing your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. Leave the `Screen` section as is but make sure you have the following sections:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 880M"
    Option     "TwinView"
    ## Screen names are laptop's: DP-3, Philips: VGA-0 and Dell:DP-2
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-2:  1920x1080, DVI-I-1: 1280x1024"
    Option         "TwinViewOrientation" "RightOf"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I am *not* an expert on xorg.conf, the above is based on my own setup which I have finally gotten to work as I wanted. You can have a look at mine [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7299878/), in case it gives you any ideas. It sets up two screens with either VGA-0 or DP-2 on the right (depending on which one is connected) and SP-3 (my laptop's) on the left.

I am pretty sure the `Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0` line in the "Server" section was very important but I did this about a year ago so I don't remember the details any more. Finally, the official [nvidia documentation](http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-7182/README/readme.txt) for `xorg.conf` is really very good and actually explains what the various options do. That and the Arch wiki [page on NVIDIA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) are what helped me solve it.

Comment: Indeed the screen is filled when I startup this way but the resolution is bad and this still doesn't explain why X can't remember to put my small screen on  the left side not to use my big screen as the main one. It's not a simple wallpaper problem, it really looks like X is getting confused and treating my small screen as my big one and my big screen as my small one.

Comment: @NicolasSeiller have you tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and then clicking on "Save to X configuration file"?

Comment: Yep tried it. upon sudo nvidia-xconfig execution I get the following output:   no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

Comment: @NicolasSeiller and? Does it remember it after reboot?

Comment: Sorry, no still the same result.

Comment: @NicolasSeiller And the `nvidia-xconfig` settings have reverted? That's weird. OK, please [edit] your question and add the output of `xrandr`. Basically, I need the names of the two screens as reported by xrandr to give you an example `xorg.conf` file. Also make sure to specify which screen should be on which side and which one should be the primary monitor.

Comment: I made the edits you asked for. Does it help ? Is there all you need ?

Comment: @NicolasSeiller that's all I need yes. Well, that's all I can use anyway, there's no guarantee this will work. I based it on my own similar setup and it should at least point you in the right direction.